# Can I centralize code that's identical but needs two different method names to properly work?

Tags: php, class, repeat

In my job, I have a lot of data to import coming from various sources that have a tendency to give "unclean" information (missing fields, typos everywhere, you name it). As such I've built a framework to automate the various verifications that need to be done for data to become suitable for production. The thing is built in PHP and I took a lot of inspiration from PHPUnit in how my thing works. Here's a part of my basic class:

```
abstract class importUnitTest
{
    public function __construct($nomTable, $conn, $niveauOutput = self::OUTPUT_ALL)
    {
        $this->nomTable = $nomTable;
        $this->conn = $conn;
        $this->testsReussis = true;
        $this->niveauOutput = $niveauOutput;
        $this->sql = "";

        $methods = get_class_methods($this);

        echo "<table class='tblUnitTest' id=\"unitTestResults\" border='1'>\n";

        forEach($methods as $method)
        {
            if($method != '__construct' && preg_match("/^test/", $method))
            {
                $this->{$method}();
            }
        }

        echo "</table>\n";
    }
}
```

Basically, what it does is, upon instanciation, it'll loop through every method of my class and execute all those that start with test. So, when I have a new type of file to test, I simply extend a class and code my verification as follow:

```
class FACT_UnitTests_BT_BC  extends importUnitTest
{
    public function test__Assureur__NotNullOrEmpty($actif = true)
    {
        $res1 = $this->champNotNull($this->getNomChamp(__FUNCTION__), $actif); 
        $res2 = $this->champNotEmpty($this->getNomChamp(__FUNCTION__), $actif);

        if(!$actif)
            $resultat = self::TEST_DESACTIVE;
        else
            $resultat = ($res1 == self::TEST_REUSSI && $res2 == self::TEST_REUSSI) ? self::TEST_REUSSI : self::TEST_ECHOUE;

        $this->genererOutput($this->getNomTestCourant(__FUNCTION__), $resultat);
        $this->testsReussis = ($this->testsReussis && ($resultat !== self::TEST_ECHOUE));
        $this->sql = "";
    }

    public function test__NoAssureur__NotNull($actif = true)
    {
        $resultat = $this->champNotNull($this->getNomChamp(__FUNCTION__), $actif);
        $this->genererOutput($this->getNomTestCourant(__FUNCTION__), $resultat);
        $this->testsReussis = ($this->testsReussis && ($resultat !== self::TEST_ECHOUE));
        $this->sql = "";
    }

    public function test__NoClient__NotNull($actif = true)
    {
        $resultat = $this->champNotNull($this->getNomChamp(__FUNCTION__), $actif);
        $this->genererOutput($this->getNomTestCourant(__FUNCTION__), $resultat);
        $this->testsReussis = ($this->testsReussis && ($resultat !== self::TEST_ECHOUE));
        $this->sql = "";
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly and allows me to automate pretty much any verification I want. However, you probably noticed that methods "NoAssureur__NotNull" and "NoClient__NotNull" have the exact same code. In a normal case, same code = same function... but in this particular case, I need the function name in order to properly determine what field I'm testing (as you probably guessed one would be NoClient and the other NoAssureur).

Lately, I found a tiny mistake in one of my tests... and I had to go back and correct it in over a hundred places (since I'm obviously copy-pasting). That's rather unacceptable maintenance-wise. So is there a better way of going about things? Is there a way to centralize test code that's the same?

Thanks in advance,

Osu

Comment: If you have more then 1 function/method that is handling the same problem and contains the same code totaly, then there is a failure in your code or architecture. Imagine you would have the same code for 1000 functions only because you need other names. I knolw this is not the real answer you want to know.

Comment: Yep, my architecture's flawed alright. That's the whole reason I'm here looking for help ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the test code in the abstract class with a field parameter and call it within the sub class with the parameter.

Something like this (parts of your actual code ommited, and a little unsure as I don't know where you're other methods are at all) :

```
abstract class importUnitTest
{
    public function isNotNull($field,$actif) {
        $resultat = $this->champNotNull($this->getNomChamp($field), $actif);
        $this->genererOutput($this->getNomTestCourant($field), $resultat);
        $this->testsReussis = ($this->testsReussis && ($resultat !== self::TEST_ECHOUE));
        $this->sql = "";
    }

//[...] omitting existing code
}


class FACT_UnitTests_BT_BC  extends importUnitTest
{
   // Omission of actual code

    public function test__NoAssureur__NotNull($actif = true)
    {
        $this->isNotNull(__FUNCTION__, $actif)
    }

    public function test__NoClient__NotNull($actif = true)
    {
        $this->isNotNull(__FUNCTION__, $actif)
    }
}
```

Again it's what came on top of my head, I may be wrong ;)

Comment: THAT is actually pretty damn clever. I can't believe I hadn't thought of that